# AngularJS Pagination with limited number of pages on UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I'm trying to do the pagination in AngularJS.
Currently I'm using [ng-simplePagination](https://github.com/svileng/ng-simplePagination) package which is very great to use,

But I want to show limited number of pages only on UI, along with next and previous buttons. 
I have gone through some of the pagination examples, but all uses bootstrap or some other directives which I don't want to install or use in my project.

Can somebody direct me to any simple angular way or package, to deal with pagination with limited number?

Comment: ngTable has a pagination that does exactly what you want, factoring out this functionality is not that hard.

Comment: @JohannesJander: Thanks! I was looking for something like ngTable. It fulfils my requirements. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`ngTable` is really good module that you can use.
 However I have found one solution [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/H4Qenm5ubIla256XW75X?p=preview) which is implemented using simplePagination only.
Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Found one more simple and elegant pagination module: **dirPaginate**.
[check here](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination)